# Python functions that can modify their own input

Tags: python

I want to create a Python function that can inspect its own input, rather than the output of its input.  For example, a function raw_str that returns its input exactly, as a string:

```
>>> raw_str(2+2)
'2+2'
```

rather than:

```
>>> str(2+2)
'4'
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is `raw_str('2+2')` acceptable?  Otherwise, @JBernardo is right.

Comment: In Ruby this is sometimes done by the library implementing such a function parsing the source of the call-site and providing the function output based on such a scan. I'm not sure how well such an approach would work in Python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible because the arguments are evaluated *before* they are passed on to the function - so there will be no way to distinguish between `2 + 2` and `3 + 1` (for instance) within the function body. Without more context, it's hard to suggest possible solutions to the problem.